# Why jQuery intermittently fails to detect click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why would jQuery sometimes detect a click and sometimes not?

I have a `#options` element that when clicked a `#dropdown-menu` is shown. When the user clicks anywhere outside the `#dropdown-menu` (except on the `#options` element) the dropdown is hidden. Here is my code that most of the time works and sometimes it doesn't:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {

    jQuery('#options').click( function(){
        jQuery('#dropdown-menu').slideDown();
    });

    jQuery(document).click( function(event) {

        if( !jQuery(event.target).closest('#dropdown-menu').length && !jQuery(event.target).is('#options') ) {

            if(jQuery('#dropdown-menu').is(":visible")) {
                jQuery('#dropdown-menu').hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I can't figure it out why it works intermittently. It is hard to accept a code that works only sometimes. I noticed that `event.target` comes back as an empty string somtimes... is this a bug with jQuery?

Edited:

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9k9ouy9z/2/) and the error can't be reproduced.

Comment: Can you reproduce with a simple jsfiddle?

Comment: live has been drecated and removed from jQuery for a long long time now. Upgrade!

Comment: @Jamiec Good idea, will do that.

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @epascarello Ok, I didn't know. But I have tried with click() function as well and got the same result.

Comment: @MikeCorcoran It is jQuery v1.11.3

Comment: You are adding an eventhandler to `document`which also includes the `#options` element. So basically you are closing your menu and re-opening it at the same time, thus resulting in your menu never closing.

Comment: I made a simple fiddle to prove it to you: https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/5rv5mh0t/

Comment: @Jorrex your code is not the same as mine. I made one as well that works and I can't reproduce this issue on fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9k9ouy9z/2/.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out the solution to my problem. Warning: it is silly and strange!

The problem was the content of `#options`, I was using an icon from FontAwesome to represent 'options' as so:

```
<div id="options"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i></div>
```

I removed the `<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>` content and added it using CSS, now it works without a fail. I am not sure why but it does; my guess is that jQuery was getting confused when I clicked on the `<i>` tag even though it belogs to `#options`.

CSS code to add FontAwesome icon:

```
#options:before {
    content: "\f142";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

(Thanks everyone's input to help me pin down this problem. I appreciate it!)